# In elisp, how can I calculate the number of days remaining until a given date?

Tags: org-mode, time-date

I feel like elisp (or org-mode) must have something like `(days-until '2018-01-01)` which would calculate the days between today and 2018-01-01. How would I go about implementing that?

Comment: Here is a link to either a related or a potential duplicate thread entitled "**Counting the number of days that have passed since a certain date**":  https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/23893/counting-the-number-of-days-that-have-passed-since-a-certain-date  If your question is a duplicate,then just delete it.  If it is somehow different, please try to distinguish your current question from the two alternative answers in the linked thread.

Comment: This isn't about counting days that have passed since a certain date, but counting days to come until a certain date.

Comment: The distance between two points is the same, whether you start from the beginning or from the end.  The difference between today looking back a day is 24 hours.  The difference between yesterday and looking forward a day to today is 24 hours.

Comment: Not sure for new year, but for Xmas it's easy, since when you use Emacs it's always Xmas.

Answer (score 5):

Found it. It's `org-time-stamp-to-now`.